# Counter MAC spoofing

Tags: iptables, mac-address, arp, spoofing

I use a public wifi. (connect with id/password on an open network)

The network is unstable (download stream 500ko/s then drop 0ko/s and stream stop, if a click a later in the stream it's working again)
With this wifi, if you use MAC spoofing you basically don't have to pay for id/password so I suspect that. (plus a lot of scan ARP request from .0 to .255 in wireshark : strange)

On my interface i have a lot of `TCP Dup ACK` and `TCP Retransmission`, and sometimes `RST` (i think RST is when the stream stop).
Is there a way to deal with this ?

Comment: What is `ko`? This is a good question, but you need to tidy-up. Proof read, be clear, spend a little time on it. If you do then you will get better answers.